# Create file on azure file storage

Tags: c#, azure

I have created file storage in Azure, can access it and verify the directory exists.  How can I create a file in the cloud directory and write to it?

Comment: Do you want to create it through code or through the Portal or through some explorer tool? And just to clarify, are you talking about Blob Storage or File Storage. Because File Storage is just an SMB share you can attach to. Of course there is a REST API too + a bunch of explorer tools.

Answer (score 2):

General info, how to work with an Azure file storage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files
How to create file and add some text:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnkqqLOOnR4

```
// Create a CloudFileClient object for credentialed access to Azure Files.
CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

// Get a reference to the file share we created previously.
CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("logs");

// Ensure that the share exists.
if (share.Exists())
{
    // Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
    CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

    // Get a reference to the directory we created previously.
    CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("CustomLogs");

    // Ensure that the directory exists.
    if (sampleDir.Exists())
    {
        // Get a reference to the file we created previously.
        CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("Log1.txt");

        // Ensure that the file exists.
        if (file.Exists())
        {
            // Write the contents of the file to the console window.
            Console.WriteLine(file.DownloadTextAsync().Result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution to upload file to Azure container in C#, here's a function I use as a utility to upload files to Azure

```
public static string UploadBlob(string blobContainerName, string key, Stream sourceStrem, string contentType)
{
    //getting the storage account
    string uri = null;
    try
    {
        blobContainerName = blobContainerName.ToLowerInvariant();
        string azureStorageAccountConnection =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageAccount"].ConnectionString;
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureStorageAccountConnection);
        CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(key);
        blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;

        blob.UploadFromStream(sourceStrem);
        uri = blob.Uri.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (_logger.IsErrorEnabled)
            _logger.Error(exception.Message, exception);
    }
    return uri;
}
```

Where blobContainerName is your container on Azure, key is the name of the file with which you want to store this blob, third parameter is the Stream of file and last one is content type.

Hope it helps

Comment: This answer is specific to blobs. Seems like the OP is asking about File Storage (smb share).

Comment: I am new to Azure and I am open to all suggestions. My objective is to extract data from the SQL db & write it to a file for the users to download later. Since my webapp(c# asp.net 4.5) will be running on Azure, the processes will not have permissions to write to any NTFS file systems. 
I set up Azure file storage and thought I could download the data into files there. Do you think a blob would be better or faster?  I cannot seem to find many examples on how to extract the data from SQL and stream 
it to a file in Azure cloud storage. Any suggestions or examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: The example above will upload any stream as a blob to azure storage. I haven't worked much with the file storage (if its anything different) so can't tell which is better. I have been working with PDF/Words and other files/documents as blobs and they work okay!

Comment: In order to get the data from Azure, you just need to setup your connection string and use an ORM like entity framework like you would do for any other SQL database locally in C#

Comment: Then you can loop through the data, write it to files (I don't exactly know what you mean here, is it simple writing?) and call the function above (if azure blob storage or different implementation if you use something different) and pass in the file stream with the name as its key and it will return you the URL of uploaded data.